# How to implement nested loops with the depth of n?

Tags: c++

The following code shows what I want to achieve. How can I generalize this principle for any value of n to generate nested loops of the same depth? Or is there a better solution?

For `n = 2`:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    }
}
```

For `n = 3`:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the loop bound `n` the same as the number of nested loops you want? Also, is this value known at compile time, or run time?

Comment: How about `for(i=0; i<n; i++) { loop(n); }`

Comment: n is obtained at run time

Comment: Do you want to do anything inside the loop? Do you need all of the indices? Please show a use case, generating empty loops is fairly simple. (But the compiler will just throw them away)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708989/generating-nested-loops-at-run-time-in-c/60709537 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737289/dynamic-nested-loops-level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567859/variadic-nested-loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Nested Loops at Run Time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708989/generating-nested-loops-at-run-time-in-c)

Comment: @KamilCuk @ hnefatl, those are all for c. This is a c+ question.

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) going on here...

Comment: The question asked is how would you implement n nested loops? there was no much info given in terms of instructions to be executed in the loops

Comment: make 1 loop, which runs `pow(n, n)` times?

Comment: Just loop to n^n in a single loop.

Comment: Try a recursive function, doing recursive calls in a single loop.

Comment: Then this sounds like a homework problem. What attempt did you make at solving it? Please try on your own before asking. See also: [How to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: How about this [song lyric generator](https://godbolt.org/z/zc3vqf)? You can enter how many verses you need and the amount of avian content in them.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708989/generating-nested-loops-at-run-time-in-c/60709342#60709342) except for C versus C++, but that is largely irrelevant in this case, except that C++ would let you dress up the interface and match it to standard C++ iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that i answered this question is; suppose we want n nested loops that is supposed to run from 1 to 10, this is how it would look

```
void nLoop(int n)
{
     if(n<=0)
         return;
     for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
     {
           nLoop(n-1);
     }
}
```